# Why are some emails marked read and others unread on arrival using IMAP in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, email-filter

On advice of my provider, I recently switched to IMAP on my desktop but left POP3 on my phone and elsewhere. Incoming email seems to randomly switch from read to unread when it appears on my desktop. That is, if 100 emails arrive at the same time, a third may appear read and the rest unread.  And they may be mixed up.
To further complicate things my mail is filtered on arrival through junk and then into some two dozen folders.

I often get as many as a thousand emails a day or more.  Keeping read and unread status clear is essential for my sanity.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: With that much correspondence, perhaps you should employ a personal assistant to process your emails.

Comment: 1) Could you switch off the devices using POP3 for a short while so that you could determine if they are setting the read/unread status? 2) Would it be possible for you to switch to IMAP everywhere?

Comment: 1) I think you have it backwards.  I have POP on my Desktop as it has more storage and IMAP on my mobile.,  2)  I have the same issue too, just haven't found a solution yet.  It only happens for google accounts, not for my domain ones.

Comment: I also have that problem (and somebody else I know as well) with certain emails, all *definitely* not having been "read" by a POP account. It's always the same sender's emails, from different senders though.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too.  Knowing that it's not just me, I found the issue.  This is for **Gmail**, other mail servers may have similar settings.

- Click on Settings (Gear icon) on right
- Click on **See All Settings**
- Under POP Download, change **When accessed by POP** to `keep Gmail's copy in the inbox`

[image: Settings]

Comment: Thanks. I also have Gmail on my desktop but the problem doesn't seem to affect mail from that account that is put in my Local Folders.

Comment: As mentioned, other mail servers may have similar settings.  Under this default setting for Gmail, as soon POP reads an email, it's marked as read, So, IMap receives that email as read.